# Continuous Deployment from GitHub failing in Azure (ASP.NET 5 & MVC 6)

Tags: c#, azure, github, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having issues with Continuous Deployment from GitHub in Azure. I have a Shared pricing tier, and the issue goes away if I upgrade to the Basic pricing tier. This is for an ASP.NET MVC 6 application (RC1).

Essentially I get the following error:
http://pastebin.com/PgARgurg

The bit that stands out is:

```
Restore failed
There is not enough space on the disk.
```

If I publish directly from Visual Studio to the Shared tier it works fine. It's only when using continuous deployment where it falls over.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Shared instances have very limited resources, especially around disk size. Continuous deployment integration from GitHub involves bringing down a copy of the code to disk upon every change, and this isn't always cleaned up immediately (or at all). A direct publish to Azure from Visual Studio does clean up the prior deployment packages automatically. The reason that upgrading your tier solves the problem is the dedicated and increased available disk space. You should upgrade to Basic if you decide that continuous integration (and thus disk space) are important to your work.

Answer (score 3):

There's another caveat. Shared Web Apps instances have a limit on [Temp Folder size of 300Mb](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3192).

An asp.net 5 RC1 application uses more Temp Folder storage than a Beta8 app. It's right now almost impossible to deploy an RC1 through Continuous Integration to a Free App Service.

Answer (score 1):

Basically restored packages size is **NOT** the same as published packages of an application.
You can understand why this is the case by opening up the restored packages...For example, in the below scenario the published package has only the required content for running the application.

**Restored** JSON.NET package content:
[image]

**Published** JSON.NET package content:
[image]

So probably you should publish the application from your continuous deployment?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Odd that it's an option for the Shared usage option, considering how small my website is!

Comment: Saying that though, the Shared option allows for 1GB disk space and I am only using 60mb (within the solution, but even looking in the packages folder it's still < 1GB)?

Comment: @AdrianLucaThomas: how much free space is available? for a out of the box MVC template, i have seen the total package size to be ~500 MB...

Comment: On the Shared option it's 1GB. However based on Matias' post it sounds like it could be an issue with the temp folder ( but that's based on a free web app, not Shared).